# I think I am singing in tune although my voice still sounds bad

Tags: voice

I really like singing, but when I sing most of the time it just sounds too monotone or awkward, I think I can hit the notes and have the correct pitch, but what can I do to get better
https://vm.tiktok.com/TTPdkpyTD2/

I’m sorry this isn’t a promotion but it’s the only way I could get a video to show my problem

Comment: Sorry, didn't listen to your example, but it's entirely possible for a sound to be perfectly "in tune", but unbearable to listen to. Autotune a baby crying to 100% pitch, it will still sound disturbing. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0Ja86JIhts Then again, if you're a good actor and have a pleasant voice and something to say both in lyrics and in emotion, you can deliver a very pleasing and convincing vocal performance even if you're nowhere near "in tune".

Comment: Turn the guitar up - it'll make you sing louder. It just sounds like you can't really be bothered.

Comment: Who would you want to sound like? In pop music you have voices like Lou Reed, Whitney Houston, and everything in between. "Good" is very subjective.

Comment: The thing that stands out the most to me is not the singing at all but the slight pause that seems to be finding the next chord on the guitar.

Answer (score 2):

So first up, I thought it sounded really nice. Super chill, very listenable. You were mostly in tune, but a few notes here and there fell out of key. Not a big deal. Your performance is very soft and pared back, which I think is a good musical choice for this song. So you're in a really good place to make it more impressive.

Some critiques that might help you to improve...

**TIP 1**

You're dynamically very flat. So you sing pretty much the same volume the whole time. Try get louder and softer. Take the bit:  "Don't mind all my friends I know they're all crazy. but they're the only friends that I have".

Try crescendo from "don't" to "they're", and then reset to the usual volume from "all crazy". And then keep the beautiful ornament you do on "I have". or try something else, whatever you like, just so long as there's an easily noticeable volume difference between your loudest and quietest note.

A phrase is some small chunk of a song that contains an idea. When singing and playing, a phrase will often be about one or two sentences, sung in one or two breaths where you cycle through the song's [usually 4] chords once. Play with dynamics within a phrase. Crescendo and decrescendo, crescendo right to the end... whatever is thematically appropriate with the lyrics. Crazy how much of a difference this makes, and not doing it is very often the source of a song sounding "boring" or "monotone".

**TIP 2**

One giveaway for non-pro singers is moments in songs that are "jarring" for one reason for another. This bit here: "I know I don't know you, but I'd like to skip the small...".

You made 4 small mistakes here. The "I know I don't" had funny tuning. Was the least accurate in the song. Then the "to" was too quiet. Also, the "to" you pronounced as "do", which was a little out of place (replacing "t" with "d" is often a great sound, but how you did it here wasn't consistent with the rest of how you styled the song). Then the chord you played for "small" came in a half beat late. (p.s. I love how you sang "small" a little after the chord was played; it's a lovely rhythmic inflection.)

Anyway, I bring these up not to be judgemental but just to point out that these inaccuracies got in the way of the otherwise nice musicality and vocal tone you had. So here it was a matter of everything that you did right sounded great, but just the things you did wrong detracted from it. Cut out those mistakes and all you're left with is the great sound.

Comment: +1 for the first sentence.  However much room for improvement there may be, this is far from "bad."

Answer (score 1):

Singing isn't just about singing in tune, singing in tune only will make you an ok singer, but the difference between ok and excellent singer is there "tone" not just singing in tune.
The bad singing tone will be:

- strainy
- breathy
- tight
- nasal

And the good will be:

- rich sounding
- resonant
- effortless

Tip: when you sing go back to your speaking voice, really just speak on the notes you will find that your tone will be incredibly better because when you speak you don't strain your voice you don't speak breathy or nasally. Most of "SLS" vocal couches will tell you that, i guess because "SLS" means speech level singing.

And do some researches about vocal tone you will find lots of videos and articles that will help you.